# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to send Auto-generated Password to the body of the Notification Email

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, mailkit

After successfully registering users, I am sending user registeration notification to users through email. I am using ASP.NET Core-6 Web API MailKit.

MailService:

```
public class MailService : IMailService
{
    private readonly MailSettings _mailSettings;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public MailService(MailSettings mailSettings, ILogger logger)

    {
        _logger = logger;
        _mailSettings = mailSettings;
    }


    public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(MailRequest mailRequest)
    {
        var email = new MimeMessage { Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Mail) };
        email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mailRequest.ToEmail));
        email.Subject = mailRequest.Subject;
        var builder = new BodyBuilder();
        if (mailRequest.Attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in mailRequest.Attachments.Where(file => file.Length > 0))
            {
                byte[] fileBytes;
                await using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
                builder.Attachments.Add((file.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), fileBytes, ContentType.Parse(file.ContentType));
            }
        }

        builder.HtmlBody = mailRequest.Body;
        email.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

        try
        {
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.Host, _mailSettings.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(_mailSettings.Mail, _mailSettings.Password);
            await smtp.SendAsync(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e, e.Source, e.InnerException, e.Message, e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

MailRequest:

```
public class MailRequest
{
    public string ToEmail { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

GetEmailBody:

```
public static async Task<string> GetEmailBody(AppUser user, string emailTempPath)
{
    var userName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(user.UserName);
    var temp = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), emailTempPath));
    var emailBody = temp.Replace("**User**", userName);
    return emailBody;
}
```

Register:

```
    public async Task<Response<string>> Register(RegisterUserDto model)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);
        user.IsActive = true;
        var response = new Response<string>();
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
                var rng = new Random();
                ulong randomNumber = rng.NextULong(1000, 9999); 
                var userPassword = "@Password" + randomNumber.ToString();
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userPassword);
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Customer);
                var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var encodedToken = TokenConverter.EncodeToken(token);
                var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                var mailBody = await EmailBodyBuilder.GetEmailBody(user, userRole.ToList(), emailTempPath: "StaticFiles/Html/ConfirmEmail.html", linkName: "ConfirmEmail", encodedToken, controllerName: "Authentication");
                var mailRequest = new MailRequest()
                {
                    Subject = "Registration Notification",
                    Body = mailBody,
                    ToEmail = model.Email
                };

                bool emailResult = await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(mailRequest); 
                if (emailResult)
                {
                    _logger.Information("Mail sent successfully");
                    var customer = new Customer
                    {
                        AppUser = user
                    };
                    await _unitOfWork.Customers.InsertAsync(customer);
                    await _unitOfWork.Save();
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                    response.Succeeded = true;
                    response.Data = user.Id;
                    response.Message = "User created successfully! Please check your mail to verify your account.";
                    transaction.Complete();
                    return response;
                }
                _logger.Information("Mail service failed");
                transaction.Dispose();
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                response.Succeeded = false;
                response.Message = "Registration failed. Please try again";
                return response;
            }
            response.Message = GetErrors(result);
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            response.Succeeded = false;
            transaction.Complete();
            return response;
        };
    }
```

EmailTemplate:

```
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; padding: 10px 20px" >UserName: **User**,</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; padding: 10px 20px" >Password: **Password**,</td>
  </tr>
```

From the EmailBodyBuilder, I've been able to send the UserName to the EmailTemplate.

How do I also send the auto-generated password (see it in Register - userPassword) from the EmailBodyBuilder to the EmailTemplate?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73549465/asp-net-core-web-api-how-to-send-registration-notification-email-without-link

Comment: No @DimitrisMaragkos. I am trying to pass the auto-generated password into the email template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that method doesn't enable you to send custom fields, you can construct your email body like this:

Html template

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; padding: 10px 20px">UserName: {0},</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.8; padding: 10px 20px">Password: {1},</td>
</tr>
```

Prepare body

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder();  
using (StreamReader SourceReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathToFile))  
{  
    builder.HtmlBody = SourceReader.ReadToEnd();  
}  

//{0} : Username  
//{1} : GeneratedPassword  

string messageBody = string.Format(builder.HtmlBody,   
    user.Username,
    generatedPassword
);
```

Comment: How do I integrate what you just give me in Prepare Body to wht I already have in GetEmailBody in my code. Thanks

Comment: When I added the code to SendEmailAsync(), I got this error:  the name user does not exist.  The name generatedPassword does not exist